# i want to count sum of specific IDs

Tags: php, mysql, count, sum

My votes table looks like in my database;

```
ID      CandidateID
1         205
2         209
3         203
4         205
5         205
6         209
```

**Code:**

```
<?php $votes_query=mysql_query("select * from votes where CandidateID='$id'");
$vote_count=mysql_num_rows($votes_query);
echo $vote_count;
?>
```

The above code gives individual results like, `CandidateID 205 =3 votes`, `CandidateID 209=2 votes`

What code can sum these votes in the table to be like,`candidateID 205 + CandidateID 209 = 3+2=5` ?

Comment: use `select sum(votes) from votes where CandidateID='$id'`

Comment: [sum](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-sum-function.htm)

Comment: if you have multiple candidate_id then use `in` clause...`select sum(votes) from votes where CandidateID in ($id)`

Comment: thanks a million man..it worked..you saved my work ..really appreciate all your responses....#1stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To Get all candidate vote count candidate-wise:**

```
<?php 
  $rs = mysql_query("select CandidateID, count(*) as vote_count from votes group by CandidateID");
  while(mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
    $CandidateID = $rs['CandidateID'];
    $vote_count = $rs['vote_count'];

    echo $CandidateID . " " . $vote_count;
  }

?>
```

**To Get Vote Count of all selected candidates**

```
<?php 
  $rs=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select count(*) as vote_count from votes where CandidateID in ($id)")); // where look like as $id = "'205','209'";
  $vote_count=$rs['vote_count'];
  echo $vote_count;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from votes where CandidateID in (1,5,7);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `COUNT` aggregate function:

```
 select count(*) as count_votes
   from votes 
  where CandidateID='$id'");
```

And be sure to use a better database approach than `mysql` functions. You should use, at least, `mysqli` functions, as they are more robust against SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can get sum of all the votes using following query:

```
select count(*) count from votes;
```

The above query can give you the total count of votes.

If you want count of individual vote from a query, you can use following query:

```
select CandidateID, count(*) count from votes group by CandidateID;
```